# unknown snap mount

Tags: gnome, mount, snap

```
david@dm:~/howto$ mount  | grep david
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_126.snap (deleted) on /media/david/disk type squashfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Can I anybody tell me what this is, and why it's there, or if it's needed?

Comment: You've not provided any release details (*though snap packages are used by all, but being specific is always helpful*), but my system includes `gnome-42-2204      0+git.ff35a85    132    latest/stable/…  canonical✓` which is used by a number of apps; including `firefox` or my web browser.  Snap packages share libraries mounted in other *snap* packages; to reduce disk space & memory (rather than each snap having its own copy in RAM)

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided any release details (*though snap packages are used by all, but being specific is always helpful*), but my system includes

`gnome-42-2204      0+git.ff35a85    132    latest/stable/…  canonical✓`

which is used by a number of apps; including `firefox` or my web browser.  Snap packages share libraries mounted in other *snap* packages; to reduce disk space & memory (rather than each snap having its own copy in RAM)

To get some info I can use the following (*which contains more details within the commands results*)

```
guiverc@d7050-next:~$   snap info gnome-42-2204 
name:      gnome-42-2204
summary:   Shared GNOME 42 Ubuntu stack
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/gnome-42-2204
contact:   https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-sdk/issues
license:   unset
description: |
  This snap provides the GNOME 42 stack to other snaps that use it. It shares the base GNOME
  libraries and desktop integration components through the content interface. This helps reduce the
  size of snaps and helps developers to easily snap desktop applications.
  
  **For users**
  
  This snap is automatically installed and removed when needed. **Manually adding or removing this
  snap is not recommended** and might break things.
  
  * If you are having issues with **snaps** using GNOME, please contact the experts on the Snapcraft
  forum: https://forum.snapcraft.io/
  * If you want to install the GNOME Desktop Environment, then you are in the wrong place. Please
  take a look at https://www.gnome.org/ for more information on how to get it.
  
  **For developers**
  
  * The `gnome` extension is the recommended way to use this in your own snap:
  https://snapcraft.io/docs/gnome-extension
  * You can report issues with this content snap on GitHub:
  https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-sdk/issues
  * The source code of this snap is available on GitHub in the `gnome-42-2204` branch:
  https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-sdk/tree/gnome-42-2204
snap-id:      lATO8HzwVvrAPrlZRAWpfyrJKlAJrZS3
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10
refresh-date: 6 days ago, at 16:05 AEST
channels:
  latest/stable:    0+git.ff35a85 2023-09-23 (132) 521MB -
  latest/candidate: 0+git.ff35a85 2023-09-27 (141) 521MB -
  latest/beta:      ↑                                    
  latest/edge:      0+git.ff35a85 2023-09-27 (141) 521MB -
installed:          0+git.ff35a85            (132) 521MB -
```